# Program works but theres a weird Recursion bug (Python)

Tags: python, recursion

```py
import sys
def get_majority_element(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr[0]

    midpoint = len(arr) // 2
    left = arr[:midpoint]
    right = arr[midpoint:]

    majority_left = 0
    majority_right = 0


    temp_left = get_majority_element(left)
    if temp_left != None:
        majority_left = temp_left



    temp_right = get_majority_element(right)
    if temp_right != None:
        majority_right = temp_right


    counterLeft = 0
    counterRight = 0

    for x in range( len(arr) ):
        if arr[x] == majority_left:
            counterLeft+=1
        elif arr[x] == majority_right:
            counterRight+=1

    if counterLeft > len(arr) // 2:
        return majority_left
        #return 1
    elif counterRight > len(arr) // 2:
        return majority_right
        #return 1
    else:
        return 0


input = sys.stdin.read()
n, *arr = list(map(int, input.split()))


result = get_majority_element(arr)
print(result)
```

****Disclaimer: The code solves the problem and passes all test cases. However.... there is a bug in the return statement that I can't quite figure out. Right now, it will return correctly the majority element in any array.

HOWEVER, If you replace the current return statements WITH the commented return statements ( return 1), the return value is not 1. How is this even possible? 
Somehow the return 1 turns into a 0 as it returns to the caller func?

Input:
5

2 3 9 2 2

output:   2

Here's the divide and conquer approach:
Say you have array a = [2 3 9 2 2]. You split it into b1 = [2 3] and b2 = [9 2 2]. You then split b1 into b11 = [2] and b12 = [3]. You then return 2 and 3, and count their occurrence in b1.

If either happens more than (n/2 = 2/2 = 1) times in b1, they are a majority element of b1. Otherwise, b1 contains no majority element and you return 0. Your program will then start recursively splitting b2 using the same procedure as above. It will then see that a majority element in b2 is 2, and count the number of its occurrences in a, to conclude that it happens more than (n/2 = 5/2 = 2) times in a and it is thus a majority element.

Comment: Why is this puzzling you exactly? You modify your return statement so of course the function will return something different. NOTE: you may return 1 at the deepest of your recursion which doesn't mean the higher level call will necessarily return 1. Add extra print statements to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: when you return 1 or 0 from all calls, you reach the top level with one of those two values for each of **majority_left** and **majority_right**.  When you look for 1's and 0's in your list, there are none.

Even if you were to take these as item counts, you'd return failure at the top level, since 1+1 is not greater than 5//2.